# MySQL/Maria DB 10.1.30: Power function Syntax error

Tags: mysql

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzSer.png)

In shell I have been trying to create the intergrated POWER Function below but I can't get it to work.  I'm sure the syntax is logically correct unless I am missing a comma. It doesn't work neither on PHPMyAdmin or Shell :

```
   DELIMITER //
   CREATE FUNCTION exponent(  m FLOAT,   n FLOAT)
   RETURNS   FLOAT ;
   BEGIN
   DECLARE a FLOAT;
   a=POW(m,n);
   RETURN a;
   END ; //
```

- Database: Default [Mysql]
- OS: Windows 10 64bit
- PHP Version: 7.2.1
- Server used: XAMPP 7.2.1

Comment: The error message quotes a semicolon before `RETURNS` which is not the code you've shared. Please double-check that you're running the correct file.

Comment: Okay, I fixed the image now.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax to assign a value to a declared procedure variable, in MySQL stored program, uses the `SET` keyword:

```
   DECLARE a INTEGER ; 
   SET a = expr ;
-- ^^^
```

Comment: Sadly it still doesnt work. My syntax is now : CREATE FUNCTION exponent( m INT, n INT) RETURNS INTEGER; BEGIN DECLARE a INTEGER; SET a=POWER(m,n); RETURN a; END ; //

Comment: Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer outside SO. The problem was that I used INT instead of FLOAT as datatype. Also there is no semicolon at RETURNS FLOAT. Full working code is:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION exponent(m FLOAT,n FLOAT)
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN
DECLARE a FLOAT  ;
SET a=POWER(m,n);
RETURN a;
END;  //
```

Use code is:

```
  DELIMITER ;
  SELECT exponent(variable1, variable 2);
```

Question is answered and can now be closed.

Comment: Using `FLOAT` as the return type restricts the returned value to the maximum value supported by `FLOAT`, about 3.4e38. Compare the return from this function `exponent(2,255)` to the return from `power(2,255)`. This function essentially casts the return from `POWER` (a `DOUBLE`) into a `FLOAT`.

Comment: 'exponent' is just the name of the function. But sure I will also try using the DOUBLE type next time.